# Cannot use software-center to install packages from local repository without internet

Tags: software-center, software-sources, localrepository

I have a Local repository as instructed in [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090731) . It is a trusted repository, so no "Authentication errors" are there. I've tested it with `synaptic` and `apt-get` .

I was being able to use this with Lucid, Natty, and Oneiric.

But I don't want to install synaptic every time, I install Ubuntu (since synaptic is removed from default Live CD since Oneiric).

The problem is : "Ubuntu Software Center" does not install packages from local repository. The install button is greyed out. It installs packages only when I connect to the Internet and for some unknown reason it re-downloads (sometimes) the packages which are also in my Local repository.

My question is: How can I use Software-Center to install packages from local repository without connecting to the internet?

### Note:

I have placed my local apt line to the top of the sources.list file and installing from `apt-get` does not require connecting to the internet

### Here is the output of command from `apt-get` :

```
anwar@Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install nautilus-wipe --print-uris 
[sudo] password for anwar: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nautilus-wipe
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 131 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/30.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 150 kB of additional disk space will be used.
'file:/media/Main/Linux-Software/Ubuntu/Precise/./precise-debs/nautilus-wipe_0.1.1-2_i386.deb' nautilus-wipe_0.1.1-2_i386.deb 30730 MD5Sum:7d497b8dfcefe1c0b51a45f3b0466994
```

It is okay with the local copy.

Ubuntu Software Center is not happy with the local copy,It always tries to connect to the internet first

[image]

And when I am not connected to Internet, The install button is grayed out.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are these .debs? When I right-click on a local .deb, I get a chance to install it via the USC.

Comment: No, not debs, I mean I have a repository in my computer (_not a full repository_). Yes, right-clicking a local deb was not also successful in Oneiric. But I don't check that in precise. (I am using Precise now)

Comment: For the right clicking .deb problem-You can use Gdebi package installer for that...Right click on .deb file>>open with Gdebi>>Install...No internet connection needed...Its the best way to install .deb files on 11.10 and 12.04...

Comment: @Nirmik I know this, But you have to manually install all dependent packages in this method. So, it doesn't seem to be an elegant solution.

Comment: Well yeah if the dependencies are not satisfied,you have to mannualy do it.(though i never faced a problem of dependacies not being satisfied)

Comment: @Nirmik, You can try installing gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad by using gdebi (You will face horrible dependency errors).

Comment: This is a bug, the link : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/911706.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have filed a bug report in launchpad. [This is the URL](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1014277) of the filed bug.

I was told that, the bug was already submitted, was a duplicate of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/911706).

The response was

> Hi Mohammed, and thank you for your report. So, as I understand it, the issue is that you want to be able to install packages using Software Center while you are not connected to the Internet, is that correct? In other words, your Internet connection is disabled at the time you try the install, and the "Install" button is disabled. If this is the case, then this bug is a duplicate of bug 911706. I will mark it as such, but please feel free to comment here if you feel this is not a duplicate of that bug. Otherwise, please add any additional info to bug 911706, and follow that one for the status of a fix.
>
> Many thanks!

The bug status was changed to **"Confirmed"** on the day 06-10-2012.

So, there is indeed no solution until this bug is fixed.

I think, this answers the question.