# How do I insert a line at the top of a text file using the command line?

Tags: apt, command-line, bash

I want to insert text at the top of an already existing file. How can I achieve this. I tried `echo` and `tee` but was not successful.

I was trying to insert repo line at the top of `sources.list` file from terminal.

### Note

I need an one line quick solution, because another answer's method was known to me already

Comment: tee adds a line at the bottom of the file e.g. `echo "deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list` -- you also need sudo before tee to get admin privileges. But why on earth would you want to add something on the very top of sources.list?

Comment: @medigeek: somewhere in the OP's question history you'll find something about installing/updating from a CD-repo...I suspect that may be the reason...

Comment: Thank @izx, Your assumption is correct. I'm quiet impressed. Can you also answer that question. That was about installing from a local repo using software-center and also setting my local repo for highest priority without placing it at the top. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you link to the question, Anwar? I'll look into it in the next day or two.

Comment: @izx, Here is the [link](http://askubuntu.com/q/135339/61218) about setting highest priority to my local repository. I will be glad if you can also check [this question about software center](http://askubuntu.com/q/137426/61218). Thanks again for your first comment. was very glad.

Comment: I have favorited that question Anwar, so it's on my "to answer" list.

Comment: @medigeek, you can see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/135339/61218) for the explanation of such an uncommon question.

Comment: There is no efficient way to do that for large files: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87772/add-lines-to-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-huge-file

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 I didn't want an efficient way

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's actually quite easy with `sed`:

- `sed -i -e '1iHere is my new top line\' filename`
- `1i` tells sed to insert the text that follows at line 1 of the file; don't forget the `\` newline at the end so that the existing line 1 is moved to line 2.

Comment: Thanks. Just for the note: if you want to replace, instead of inserting use `s` instead of i in `1i`.

Comment: Sadly this fails for the empty file (it has no fist line, so sed never inserts).

Comment: @Tino For empty files you can just use `echo "Text Here" >> Filename`

Comment: doesn't work on MacOS 10

Comment: Just want to add that on `Ubuntu 20.04` the '\' newline gets output to the file, it is not needed (at first I had to escape the '\' in my text editor, but later removed the '\' and it seems to insert a newline fine.

Comment: With `sed 4.4` on `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`, no need to add `\\` at the end

Answer (score 8):

In general editing in place with a script is tricky, but you can use `echo` and `cat` and then `mv`

```
echo "fred" > fred.txt
cat fred.txt t.txt >new.t.txt
# now the file new.t.txt has a new line "fred" at the top of it
cat new.t.txt
# can now do the rename/move
mv new.t.txt t.txt
```

**However** if you're playing with sources.list you need to add in some validation and bullet-proofing to detect errors etc because you really don't want to loose this.  But that's a separate question :-)

Comment: I can do that already. I need a one line solution as izx gave. however thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AnwarShah - ah sorry! You should have said that in your question :-)

Comment: I admit, +1 for your answer and also for comment. *(I can't give more)*

Answer (score 6):

```
./prepend.sh "myString" ./myfile.txt
```

known that `prepend` is [my custom shell](https://github.com/abdennour/miscs.sh/blob/master/prepend.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
#add Line at the top of File
# @author Abdennour TOUMI
if [ -e $2 ]; then
    sed -i -e '1i$1\' $2
fi
```

Use also a relatif path or absolute path , it should work fine :

```
./prepend.sh "my New Line at Top"  ../Documents/myfile.txt
```

## Update :

if you want a permanent script for this , open `nano /etc/bash.bashrc` then add this function at the end of file:

```
function prepend(){
# @author Abdennour TOUMI
if [ -e $2 ]; then
    sed -i -e '1i$1\' $2
fi

}
```

Reopen you terminal and enjoy :

```
prepend "another line at top" /path/to/my/file.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

And why not use a genuine text editor for that? *ed* is the standard text editor.

```
ed -s filename <<< $'1i\nFIRST LINE HERE\n.\nwq'
```

Or, if you want the commands to be more readable:

```
ed -s filename < <(printf '%s\n' 1i "FIRST LINE" . wq)
```

- `1`: go to firstline
- `i`: insert mode
- *your stuff you want to insert...*
- `.`: stop inserting, go back to normal mode
- `wq`: write and quit, thank you, good bye.

Comment: How to use shell variables substitution(in the `FIRST LINE`) with this?

Comment: @vp_arth If your content is in variable `first_line` then: `ed -s filename < <(printf '%s\n' 1i "$first_line" . wq)`. Make sure that the variable doesn't expand to a single dot, and doesn't contain any newline characters (so sanitize it if it comes from user input).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -s -c '1i|hello world' -c -x sources.list
```

1. `1` select 1st line
2. `i` insert new line of text
3. `x` save and close

Comment: Much simpler than other solutions provided so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is always the `awk` option. Replace `string` variable with your contents. This is not an in-place change though. Personally, I tend to not make in-place changes. This is definitely a personal preference. Two things, `-v` signifies a variable in awk and variable `n` is used here to match a line number, effectively `NR == 1`. You could use this in any number of ways just by changing the value of `n` and `s`.

```
string="My New first line"; awk -v n=1 -v s="$string" 'NR == n {print s} {print}'     file.source > file.target
```

Example:

```
% cat file.source                                                                                                                                      

First Line
Second Line
Third Line

% string="Updated First Line"; awk -v n=1 -v s="$string" 'NR == n {print s} {print}' file.source > file.target; cat ./file.target                      !698

Updated First Line
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
```